# How do i setup a highscore system in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to setup a highscore system in unity such that less the time better the higscore..... and i want to display that highscore when the player dies with the current score.... i have managed to set the current score text but i am not able to do set the high score

here is my code for score system:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private float scoreMultiplier = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text scoreText;

    public float score;

    private void Update() {
        score += Time.deltaTime * scoreMultiplier;
        scoreText.text = "Time: " + score.ToString("#.00");
    }
}
```

and this is where i set my current score text:

```
    public void LevelComplete() {
        levelCompleteUI.SetActive(true);

        var currentScore = _scoreManager.score;
        currentScoreText.text = "Current Time: " + currentScore.ToString("#.00");

        Cursor.visible = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        _camController.enabled = false;
        _playerMover.enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you write your `_scoreManager`, but by you store your score there,
you should store your high score data there as well, something like `_scoreManager.highScore`. Set default value to 0, and write something like

```
if(_scoreManager.score >= _scoreManager.highScore){
    _scoreManager.highScore = _scoreManager.score;
}
// print out high score
```

in your `LevelComplete()` will do. Hope this helps.

Comment: but how do i store the high score like should i just use PlayerPrefs.SetFlot() in update.... will that work??

Comment: can you show that part of the codes? As long you have different keys for normal score and high score, should be able to store different value.